# % (joker) does not work in my sql query with IN operator

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am reading out a database table, and excluding some rows with given values in a column.

But i cant get the query to get the right number for me. I suspect it still counts the kampanje*_xxxxx* rows. I use `%` to exclude.

```
$sql = 
    "SELECT * 
     FROM salg 
     WHERE 
         fnr='$fnr' 
         AND kategori NOT IN ('tilbehor', 'servicekontrakt', '%kampanje%') 
         AND dato BETWEEN '$fdato' AND '$tdato'"
;

 $kjor = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
 $faste .=  mysqli_num_rows($kjor). ", ";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IN` comparison operator takes list of values, it does not recognizes wildcards such as `%`. So your assumption that *it still counts the kampanje_xxxxx rows* is correct, since MySQL is actually searching for a litteral `'%kampanje%'` value.

You would need to create a separate `LIKE` condition to check the column againts the value that contains the wildcard. I believe that your query can be expressed as follows :

```
SELECT * 
FROM salg 
WHERE 
    fnr='$fnr'
    AND kategori NOT IN ('tilbehor', 'servicekontrakt')
    AND kategori NOT LIKE '%kampanje%'
    AND dato BETWEEN '$fdato' AND '$tdato'
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use OR not like  and avoid wild char in IN set of values

```
"SELECT * 
FROM salg 
WHERE fnr='$fnr' 
AND ( kategori NOT IN ('tilbehor', 'servicekontrakt') 
        OR NOT LIKE concat('%','kampanje','%') )
AND dato BETWEEN '$fdato' AND '$tdato'";
```

anyway you should avoid the use of php var in sql  .. you are at risk for  sqliject .. try take a look at ypour db driver for prepared  statements and binding param

for see  error eventually try show the exact erro message using

```
if (!$kjor) {
 printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $connect->error);
}
```

Comment: This one gives a mysqli_num_rows error when i try to count the rows. Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Comment: .. Answer updated .. but  are you sure you are connect?   .. and if you are connected  try obtain the exact error message from sql  ..

Comment: Yes, im connected. All other querys runs without a hitch. :/

Comment: Errormessage: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE concat('%','kampanje','%') ) AND dato BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2019-02-10'' at line 5

Comment: `OR NOT LIKE concat` is missing a column name somewhere.  Also not sure why the `concat` is needed.